# Android send SMS set destination port Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, sms

This code from the Xamarin documentation provides two methods to send an SMS. The first method as shown below does not have any port related parameters:

```
SmsManager.Default.SendTextMessage ("1234567890", null,
"Hello from Xamarin.Android", null, null);
```

The second method:

```
var smsUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("smsto:1234567890");
var smsIntent = new Intent (Intent.ActionSendto, smsUri);
smsIntent.PutExtra ("sms_body", "Hello from Xamarin.Android");  
StartActivity (smsIntent);
```

How do I set the destination port of an SMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any port-addressed SMS message is handled as data (binary) SMS, at least in Android.

In order to send a message to a specific port with `SmsManager`, you must use the `SendDataMessage()` method. If the receiving app is listening for a text message on a specific port, then it will (presumably) know how to decode the data as plain text.

Starting another SMS app to handle the send - as shown in your second method - is not a likely option. Your run-of-the-mill SMS clients are probably not going to deal with data messages at all. The platform app, for example, does not handle them, and the SMS Provider simply discards them. If, by chance, a user has one that does, your app would need to know the key and data format it expects on the `Intent`, for which there is no *de facto* standard, as far as I'm aware.

Additionally, if your app needs to handle incoming port-addressed messages, it will need a Receiver configured for data SMS. The `IntentFilter` will have the action `"android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED"`, a data scheme of `"sms"`, and the data port, which can either be specific, or the wildcard `"*"` to listen on all ports.

Answer (score 0):

[SMSManager.SendDataMessage()](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Telephony.Gsm.SmsManager.SendDataMessage/p/System.String/System.String/System.Int16/System.Byte%5B%5D/Android.App.PendingIntent/Android.App.PendingIntent/) has a PORT argument

Comment: When I use send data message, the cell phone receiving the message claims its an instance of a BinaryMessage instead of a TextMessage. Is there some extra text message header required?

Comment: no idea, before this I wasn't even aware SMS had port numbers